I have a feed of a thin sheet of material, how tocalculate the amount you can twist that film along the axis based on its dimensional properties?
If I have a feed of a thin sheet of material (for example a 35mm film like you would use in a camera), how do you calculate the amount you can twist that film along the axis of its direction of travel based on its dimensional properties (thickness and width mainly)?
It feels intuitive to say that it would be easy to twist the film 180º slowly throughout a large length, but not easy to do so in a short distance without it folding or being damaged. It also feels intuitive to say that the less wide the film is, the easier it is to twist, and vice versa.
What formula can be used to calculate this behavior?

You can turn a sheet of film $180^\circ$ in a very short distance if you're willing to let it change its direction of travel. I think to do what you seem to want to do requires the film to be able to stretch a little bit, because the centerline of the film is a straight line while the edges trace helical paths. Stretching is a material property that seems to require more than just pure math to know.

The ribbon takes the shape of a developable surface. If you know the formula that describes  how the  curved center-line of the ribbon  is positioned in space (parametrized by its arclength), the remainder of the surface shape can be fully reconstructed (details in Graustein's paper).  The  features of the parametrized curve that you need to know are called its curvature $\kappa$ and torsion $\tau$  which describe the so-called Frenet frame  associated to the curve(see e.g Struik or Wikipedia for their definitions).
Sadowsky proposed a formula for the bending energy stored in a narrow ribbon: $\int  \kappa^2 (1+\eta^2)^2 $ where $\eta=\kappa/\tau$. This formula can be found as eq 2.2, 2.3 in the article by Fried and Chen.
Some references to get you started learning the relevant vocabulary of twisted paper surfaces:
D. Fuchs, S. Tabachnikov, Mathematical Omnibus: Thirty Lectures on Classic Mathematics, AMS 2007
More on Paperfolding
Author(s): Dmitry Fuchs and Serge Tabachnikov
Source: The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 106, No. 1 (Jan., 1999), pp. 27-35
Y. Chen and E. Fried, Mobius bands, unstretchable material sheets and developable surfaces, Proceedings of the Royal Society A, (2016)
On the Geodesics and Geodesic Circles on a Developable Surface
Author(s): William Caspar Graustein
Source: Annals of Mathematics, Second Series, Vol. 18, No. 3 (Mar., 1917), pp. 132-138 Published by: Annals of Mathematics
Struik: Lectures on Classical Differential Geometry
(Dover reprint)
You may find this recent preprint of interest too:
The Optimal Paper Moebius Band
Richard Evan Schwartz ∗ October 15, 2024
Speaking informally, if you start with the flat ribbon oriented North South and draw a collection of crease lines  extending from the left edge of the ribbon (resembling a collection of railroad ties that are no longer parallel E-W, but rather of varying directions generally pointing NE), then you can roll up the ribbon along these crease lines to make it curl in space. There is some freedom in how intensely you perform this rolling operation as you move along the ribbon, which allows you to create different shapes. You can actually do this by gliding the edge of a scissor blade along a strip of paper to make a curled ribbon. Each instantaneous position of the blade is a crease line.
If the ribbon is made too wide the surface crashes into itself (develops singularities).
The singularities occur when the crease lines you drew on the flat ribbon collide.  The caustic the crease lines  create is typically a curve on the flat paper, called the envelope of the family of crease lines. Each crease line is a tangent line to the caustic curve. The rate at which the tangent vector to this caustic curve rotates is $\kappa$.
Thus $\kappa$ describes the rate of rotation of the plane  crease lines,  and one can regard $\tau$ as describing the rate at which you curl up the paper  as you travel from one line to the next. In fact $\tau$ is the rate of rotation of the normal vector to the paper as you curl up the paper.
